# Microsoft.Maui not recognized after upgrading solution from Xamarin.Forms to Maui and other issues (net8.0)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, migration, maui

I just migrated my solution to Maui with net8.0 using the .NET upgrade assistant and am having a number of issues that I am struggling to figure out on my own.

1. My "Colors" class that extends ResourceDictionary (Microsoft.Maui.Controls) does not seem to recognize the Microsoft.Maui library.
   [Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4tff.png)
2. For some reason net8.0 is not available in my android project only, but it is in others.
   [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VErW.png)
3. I have a bunch of these errors XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage". for my xaml files.
   [Error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFzyt.png)

I would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions on how to fix these issues. Thank you.

I have installed the latest runtimes and updates for .Net 8.0 and have the latest version of VS 2022 with all the required addons.

Comment: If you create a new Maui app, can it be successfully built?